# How to save a color

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Okay so I've tried using floats and strings but they don't seem to work. The console just throws up cannot convert type bleh to type bleh. I've looked this up and people suggest using `PlayerPrefs.SetColor` but it seems as if unity have got rid of that. I'm not really sure how I'm suppose to save a color now. I did find this on the unity website, however I'm unsure on how to implement it.

```
Renderer rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
rend.material.shader = Shader.Find("Specular");
rend.material.SetColor("_SpecColor", Color.red); Any help here?
```

any help?

okay so this is what i tried:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("myColor1", Title.myColor1);
PlayerPrefs.SetString("myColor2", Title.myColor2);
```

and on another script:

```
myColor1 = PlayerPrefs.GetString("myColor1");
myColor2 = PlayerPrefs.GetString("myColor2");
```

Comment: Could you paste the code you are trying and the exact error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [ArrayPrefs2](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ArrayPrefs2) so you can just use `PlayerPrefsX.SetColor()` and `PlayerPrefsX.GetColor()` or take it as reference to do some specific to your needs.

**edited:** To be more specific, you need to copy the content of this PlayerPrefsX class provided into a PlayerPrefsX class somewhere in your scripts (there are c# and unity script versions). Or just use that code as you want to create another helper as you wish.

Comment: I read about that though when i type it in it tells me it doesnt exist in the current context

Comment: Did you add the script to your project? If you read the the entire wiki page linked above you'll see that it's not provided by unity itself but it's a class given on that wiki page ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the color to string using Unity ColorUtility

```
const string Key = "my_stored_color";

public void SetColor(Color color)
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString(Key, ColorUtility.ToHtmlStringRGBA(color));
}

public Color GetColor()
{
    var storedColorAsString = "#" + PlayerPrefs.GetString(key);
    Color result;
    ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString(storedColorAsString, out result);
    return result;
}
```

Make sure to add the # before parsing